# Arch Arm: /folder does not support NFS export

Tags: backup, nfs, hfs+, arm, arch-linux

I have a backup drive that is formatted hfs+ (for my mac laptops) That I want to have available on my home network so I don't have to plug in directly.
I have a pogoplug running arch linux (install is 3 days old with a 4gb flash drive as the disk), so I thought that if I could serve up the drive via nfs I could have wifi backup per this site:
http://blog.mediafederation.com/andy-hawkins/mac-os-x-time-machine-via-nfs-on-linux-ubuntu-complete-guide-fixes-error-13-etc/

which would be swell, but when I try to export a folder (any folder I've tried) I get the error: "exportfs: /backup does not support NFS export". I read somewhere that nfs does not work on certain file systems, but I don't know anything more about that.

My nfs server seems to be running fine, on my other machine I get

> rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.71 | grep nfs

```
100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
```

and no errors anywhere, I built hfsprogs and that is working--I can navigate and mount the hfs+ drive, but I cannot serve it up.

Why can I not serve it up? Any ideas?
Should I try to make another partition that is a different file system and mount onto that and serve it up?

I'll be glad to answer any requests for more information about the setup. I am familiar with the bash shell, but if you want me to run an arch flavor command, you should probably type it out.

Comment: Since NFS uses an in-kernel server, the ability to export filesystems somewhat depends on that filesystem's driver. It could be that HFS just doesn't have this implemented yet.

Comment: I cannot export the regular folders either.

Comment: After doing a little more searching (prompted by your comment, @grawity) it seems that NFS cannot serve up HFS[+] unless it is compiled into the kernel.

Comment: @JoshRagem Help the community and supply what you found as an answer and... I think it takes a day or two before you can... then select your own answer as the right one! Please do this, we all benefit!

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was unable to serve up any folders is probably the two file system type I am dealing with.
For the HFS+, NFS cannot serve it up without the support being compiled into the kernel. NFS is an in-kernal server (@grawity) which can give it speed.
The other system is ext2, which is plenty old. I was using nfs4 to try to export it and it doesn't surprise me that it didn't work.

I will be trying netatalk and AFP to serve up the backup drive.